# Create custom object from List<T> using .Linq

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to create a multidimensional array and afterwords using this same multidimensional array to create charts, but I don't know how to make this.

The logic I'd like to achive is below.

```
//T070_RESULT is an entity .Linq

public int id { get; set; }
public string entidade { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> entidadeID { get; set; }
public string unidadeMedida { get; set; }        //not relevant for this question
public string valor { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> date { get; set; }

//this list contains objects with the structure above
List<T070_RESULT> resultados = ListOfResults(idSample);
```

imagine this example (resultados list):

```
[id, entidade, entidadeID, unidadeMedida, valor, date] 
[1, EntityX, 10, 10, 100, 01-09-16]
[2, EntityX, 10, 10,  80, 02-09-16]
[3, EntityX, 10, 10, 120, 01-10-16]
[4, EntityZ, 10, 10, 100, 01-09-16]
[5, EntityZ, 10, 10, 110, 01-10-16]
```

now I'd like to create a multidimensional array grouped by date and having this results below:

new object would be generated from the input above:

EntityX_Value(summed values for that month of that year) would be one column with all values grouped by date

EntityZ_Value the same

```
[id, EntityX_Value(summed values for that month of that year), EntityZ_Value, date]
[1, 180, 100, 01-09-16] 
[2, 80,  110, 01-10-16]
```

(regarding dates, i don't need the day, i just need this grouped by month and year)

how can I do this, using linq or other methodology ?

Comment: There are a few problems with this question. 1) There is no multidiensional array anywhere. 2) `09-16` is not a representation of a `DateTime`. 3) what is `EntityX_Value` and `EntityZ_Value`? (your input has `unidadeMedida` and `valor`) 4) where does the `id` in the result come from?

Comment: Or, more basically, explain how you get from your example input to your example output, and the answer will be easy.

Comment: you want to get an output of `string[]`?

Comment: maybe the multidimensional array is not the best aproach at all, maybe other kind of object to achieve this purpose.

Comment: @Jamiec please review the question, I hope i've ansewered to your, regarding the id it doesent't matter how is generated it can be a sequence.

Comment: `would be one column with all values grouped by date` - all values of *what*? (`valor`??)

Comment: yes ( valor = value ) , sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, based on the fact you commented that entities could by dynamic (ie, more than just `EntityX` and `EntityZ`).

The first thing to do is work out which entities you have, thats as easy as selecting them from the list and using `Distinct`. Then you need to group by month & year, and use the entity list to build up something like a dictionary (key=Entity name value=sum of `valor`).

This would work.

```
// get a distinct list of entities
var entities = list.Select(x => x.entidade).Distinct();

// group your original list, and use the above list to search for the right results
var result = list.GroupBy( x => new {Month = x.date.Value.Month, Year = x.date.Value.Year})
    .Select( (x,i) => new {
        id = (i+1),
        values = entities.ToDictionary(k => k, v => x.Where(y => y.entidade == v).Sum(y => y.valor)),
        date = new DateTime(x.Key.Year, x.Key.Month,1)
    });
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/RGV51846

Comment: Excuse my use of english variable names. Without knowing how to pluralise `entidade` and `valor` I did not want to confuse things.

Comment: no problem, my bad! just one question, i've tested but the Sum(y => y.valor) is not adding the other values from the same dates, regarding the rest I think is this what i was looking for

Comment: @PTLearner - I made one assumption, and changed one thing. In your example `valor` is a string. I changed it to an int. You can always do `.Sum(y => int.Parse(y.valor))` (or `double.Parse` if more appropriate). Better would be to use a numerical type in the first place if you're doing arithmetic on it. Look at my live example if you're unsure.

Comment: yes I've done that, I'll look into it and set the ansewer as correct as soon I finnish this

Answer (score 0):

Bit confusing, but taking from your expected output, you need grouping on `date` and do something like this.

```
var result = resultados.GroupBy(x=>x.date)
          .Select((x,i)=>
           {
               id = i+1,
               EntityX_Value = x.Where(w=>w.entidade == "EntityX").Sum(s=>s.valor),
               EntityZ_Value = x.Where(w=>w.entidade == "EntityZ").Sum(s=>s.valor), 
               date = x.Key 
           });
```

Comment: it's almost this, i've given that example but we have to assume that the number of entities increase or might be only one, how can i do this dinamiclly ?

Comment: Hmm, that's bit challenging but what you could do is grouping again `entitiy` and then try to pivot the results by grouping them on date again.

Comment: well that seems to work, but i'm a bit new at .Linq and i don't know how to make a pivot table using this aproach